# BigQuery not saving Firebase event data into daily tables

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have an app that is using Firebase Analytics and the data goes into BigQuery in 4 different datasets: `android`, `ios`, `android_dev`, `ios_dev`. All the datasets are creating their daily `app_events_x` tables correctly except for the android dataset (`android_dev` is working correctly).

I only have one daily table `app_events_20170223` (the day when android build went live) even though events are being sent every day. Intraday table has events in it so the events are coming through and get registered. But the next day the data of yesterday is no where to be seen.

I checked the `app_events_20170223` in case of the data would all get saved in the same one table for some reason but it only has events from 2017/02/23 like it should. Also the intraday table has only the events belonging to current day like it should.

So how should I start to figure out what's wrong and how to fix this? All help is much appreciated.

Comment: Leave here the project id if a google engineer will see this post should know what to check, other than this open an official support case.

Comment: *firebaser here* There is little anyone here can do. Please [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: Could you please project name, dataset name and related table name? One of my co-worker could have a look.

Comment: @miarkito how did you solve it at the end? I am facing same issue

Comment: @elvainch We had forgotten to turn off the debug mode ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview ). If the debug mode is enabled the events don't get saved to daily tables.